# Como tener Firebase ejecutado en segundo plano?

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo una actividad principal donde veo que si no tengo internet en el `onCreate`, el `Firebase` (**El cual tiene su propia `AsyncTask`**) no hace su trabajo, entonces el problema es que si no obtengo informacion del `Firebase`, no puedo hacer hacer el setter del adaptador con la informacion y se me quedaria la actividad vacia. Mi pregunta es, como llevar a cabo la tarea de obtencion continua del `Firebase` si no tengo internet? Como puedo obtener la base de datos de `FB` una vez conectado a internet?

He probado los siguientes metodos para hacer un boolean de si estoy conectado o no y no me servian de nada... aun teniendo el wifi me saltaba mi aviso que no estaba conectado...

```
public boolean isOnline() 
{
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

y

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
     ConnectivityManager connectivity =(ConnectivityManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return false;
    }
```

Si el Firebase tiene su propio "doInBackground" debido a su `Asynctask`, porque al conectarme a internet (wifi o 3g) no me da la informacion para adaptarla?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfecto! RESUELTO!

`Firebase` al tener integrado `AsyncTask` implemento dentro de un metodo (El primer parametro es `Context` donde quiero ejecutar el `Firebase`, y el segundo parametro el `GridView` donde quiero añadir el `setAdapter`).

Al ejecutarlo en el `onCreate` de la actividad principal: Si no estoy conectado he puesto que lance un `Toast`, y sino que haga un `onDataChange` (Metodo del FB) + `setAdapter` en el `GridView` que le paso como segundo parametro. 
Funciona perfectamente, sin ningun problema!

Espero que os haya servido de algo la explicacion!

Answer (score 2):

Este método es más útil, el cual revisa si hay conectividad la cual puede ser Wifi (`ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI`) ó GPrS (`ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE`):

```
public Boolean isNetAvailable(Context context)  {      
        try{
           ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)                                                                               context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
          NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                if (wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Exception Connectivity", e.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Con esto puedes realizar tu validación.

recuerda agregar el permiso en el `Manifest.xml`:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

si no lo tenias, esto puede ser la causa de que tu método no pudiera funcionar adecuadamente:

Comment: Funciona perfectamente! era lo que necesitaba! Muchas gracias!